# Quickblox error "incorrect event" sending a push notification with AP

Tags: php, quickblox

I'm using Quickblox to send push notifications to iPhone users. I created PHP functions for session and creating a user and API is working fine, but testing sending a push notification, I got an error on Dashboard/Queue: "incorrect event" on the message column. The event is created but never arrived.
The response of the API is OK, like the documentation.
I don't know why I got that error.

This is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['mensaje'])) {
    // Quickblox user Sign Up
    $session = createSession( . . . , '...', '...', '...', '...');
    $token = $session->token;
    $group = '...'; // Hardcoded only for testing
    $resp = sendQBPush($_POST['mensaje'], $group, $token);
}
```

and the function:

```
function sendQBPush($msg, $group, $token)
{
    if (!$msg) {
        return false;
    }

    $message = base64_encode($msg);

    // Build post body
    $post_body = array(
        'event' => array(
            'notification_type' => 'push',
            'environment' => 'production',
            'user' => array(
                'tags' => array(
                    'any' => $group
                )
            ) ,
            'push_type' => 'apns',
            'message' => 'payload=' . $message
        )
    );
    $request = json_encode($post_body);
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.quickblox.com/events.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Use POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request); // Setup post body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0',
        'QB-Token: ' . $token
    ));
    $resultJSON = curl_exec($ch);
    $responseJSON = json_decode($resultJSON);
    echo $resultJSON;

    // Check errors
    if ($responseJSON) {
        return $responseJSON;
    }
    else {
        $error = curl_error($curl) . '(' . curl_errno($curl) . ')';
        return $error;
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Thanks for your help